# How to render array of lines to <textarea>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textarea

I'm on **Ruby 2.0** and **Rails 4**, and trying to render an array of lines to `f.text_area` form helper using:

```
<%= f.text_area :sources_text, value: ['1', '2'].join('\n') %>
```

I expect to get:

```
1
2
```

as the `<textarea>` value but I get:

```
1\n2
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the helper the value is being rendered as a string.

So to have

```
1
2
```

you have to have the value be `"1\n2"`

so if you have an array **t** then:

```
  <%t=['1','2']%>
  <%= f.text_area :sources_text, value: t.join("\n") %>
```

and you will have in the text area

```
1
2
```

Comment: This is a good first answer. Best to mix **Code** with **Explanation**

Comment: Except he forgot to explain the actual problem - `''` vs `""` - while fixing it /in-passim/!

Answer (score 5):

**Use:** `"\n"`. The `'\n'` version used single quotes `''`, which escape almost nothing.

**Dev tip**: Always prefer `''` unless you actually need `""`'s special powers (*which you do need, here*).